# How to properly dynamically allocate array in C?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

When allocating array in C, what is the difference between the below two -

```
 int n;
 scanf("%d",&n);
 int array[n];
```

And

```
 int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

I know that the second one is dynamic allocation of array, which gets allocated from heap. But I am unable to figure out how the first method works. Does it allocate array on runtime, after getting the value for `n`? And which one should I be using?

Comment: First one is *VLA* (variable length array) which has an automatic storage class (that is only lives in the block scope, and usually allocated on stack)

Comment: The VLA is convenient for small arrays (the stack is not as large as the heap), but not all compilers support it. Also, it dies when you return from the function, but the dynamic allocation does not.

Comment: There is also a non-standard function [alloca](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) that lets you allocate space on the stack. It looks like malloc in that it returns a pointer but the space gets automatically freed on return from the function like in the first case. So there is a mechanism for allocating chunks of stack at will.

Comment: When to use VLA (the first case): stack can be fairly limited and if you exceed it, your program will unceremoniously crash, so use it only for small arrays. This feature is also not available in C++, so if you plan on using that, don't get too attached to VLAs. On the other hand, it is convenient that you don't have to keep track of freeing it, so it can be nice.